# How to auto select a particular option

Tags: javascript, converters, currency, shopify

My site uses a currency converter (shopify) and even though my store accepts GBP I want to auto-select the currency USD so that upon entereing the site, prices are converted to USD

The following is my currency converter code

```
<label for="currencies">Currency converter </label>
<select id="currencies" name="currencies">
  {% capture codes     %},USD,EUR,GBP,CAD,ARS,AUD,BBD,BDT,BSD,BHD,BRL,BOB,BND,BGN,MMK,KYD,CLP,CNY,COP,CRC,HRK,CZK,DKK    ,DOP,XCD,EGP,XPF,FJD,GHS,GTQ,GYD,GEL,HKD,HUF,ISK,INR,IDR,NIS,JMD,JPY,JOD,KZT,KES,KWD,LVL,LTL,M    XN,MYR,MUR,MDL,MAD,MNT,MZN,ANG,NZD,NGN,NOK,OMR,PKR,PYG,PEN,PHP,PLN,QAR,RON,RUB,SAR,RSD,SCR,SGD    ,SYP,ZAR,KRW,LKR,SEK,CHF,TWD,THB,TZS,TTD,TRY,UAH,AED,UYU,VEB,VND,ZMK,{% endcapture %}
  {% assign supported_codes = settings.supported_currencies | split: ' ' %}
  <option value="{{ shop.currency }}" selected="selected">{{ shop.currency }}</option>
  {% for code in supported_codes %}
    {% if code != shop.currency and codes contains code %}
   <option value="{{ code }}">{{ code }}</option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

How can I auto-select USD to show?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with javascript like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/83wHb/

Basically you want to run a script onload that sets the value of currencies to USD.

Ideally you'd wanna run the script onload, or right after the select element is rendered.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('currencies').value = "USD";
//console.log('current value selected: ' + document.getElementById('currencies').value);
</script>
```

Alternatively (and probably better), you could do it server side like this:

```
<label for="currencies">Currency converter </label>
<select id="currencies" name="currencies">
    {% capture codes %},USD,EUR,GBP,CAD,ARS,AUD,BBD,BDT,BSD,BHD,BRL,BOB,BND,BGN,MMK,KYD,CLP,CNY,COP,CRC,HRK,CZK,DKK    ,DOP,XCD,EGP,XPF,FJD,GHS,GTQ,GYD,GEL,HKD,HUF,ISK,INR,IDR,NIS,JMD,JPY,JOD,KZT,KES,KWD,LVL,LTL,M    XN,MYR,MUR,MDL,MAD,MNT,MZN,ANG,NZD,NGN,NOK,OMR,PKR,PYG,PEN,PHP,PLN,QAR,RON,RUB,SAR,RSD,SCR,SGD    ,SYP,ZAR,KRW,LKR,SEK,CHF,TWD,THB,TZS,TTD,TRY,UAH,AED,UYU,VEB,VND,ZMK,{% endcapture %}
      {% assign supported_codes = settings.supported_currencies | split: ' ' %}
      <option value="{{ shop.currency }}" >{{ shop.currency }}</option>
      {% for code in supported_codes %}
        {% if code != shop.currency and codes contains code %}
           {% if code == 'USD' %}
              <option value="{{ code }}" selected="selected"> {{ code }}</option>
           {% else %}
              <option value="{{ code }}">{{ code }}</option>
           {% endif %}
         {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to do it server side using that code but it didn't work my shop.currency is GBP but want it to auto select USD

Comment: It looks like shopify auto-sets your default currency based on your location, so maybe try using the JavaScript solution so it auto switches the drop down on page load?

Comment: I've used the on page load method, however when you choose to select e.g. GBP, and move onto a new page it changes it back to USD. Is there anyway to stop this change happening if you choose another currency?